# MS SQL Express size limit exceeded - how?

Tags: sql-server

Our customer has issue with restoring database backup in MS SQL Express due to size limit (10 GB).
But this backup was created in MS SQL Express too.
Is there the possibility to somehow exceed size limit of MS SQL Express?
There are some varbinary filesteam columns but if I am not wrong these should not be taken into account for size limit.
MS SQL server version should be 2017 or 2019.

Error message: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: What is the error he gets?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "*There are some varbinary filesteam columns but if I am not wrong these should not be taken into account for size limit.*" - What makes you believe that?...my understanding is anything that contributes to the size of the database counts. What is the current size of the source database?

Comment: regarding varbinary filestream, I found this info here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-compatibility-with-other-sql-server-features?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15 (section 'SQL Server Express')

one additional info, used space of customer's database was only around 3 GB, the rest was reserved space after data deletion.